# Qt and audio playback

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I'm trying to get some audio in my Qt desktop application, however all seems FUBAR. I tried QSound, like this:

```
QSound *sound=new QSound("/home/kajos/Projects/Flatland-build-desktop/mario.wav", this);
sound->setLoops(3);
sound->play();
```

and Phonon like this:

```
QFile file("mario.mp3");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    qDebug("Music not found");
} else {
    Phonon::MediaObject *mediaObject = Phonon::createPlayer(Phonon::MusicCategory);

    mediaObject->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(&file));
    mediaObject->play();
}
```

QSound doesn't do anything (with mid, mp3, wav) and Phonon throws this error:

```
ASSERT: "d->connected" in file ../../phonon/streaminterface.cpp, line 89
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Any idea on how to get some sound in my app? I can play sounds fine on my system, ubuntu 11.10.
I'm open to midi only suggestions, since that is what I would like to focus on if possible.

I read with a similar case with Phonon, that it happens in debug mode, but I would like to debug.

Comment: Did you try with Qt Mobility's QMediaPlayer? It uses GStreamer as a backend so if you can play your midi file with gst-launch like this then it will probably work in Qt Mobility:
gst-launch playbin2 uri=file:///path/to/audio.mid
You might need gst-plugins-bad to get midi support though.

Comment: I can't use Qt Mobility on the desktop, right?

Comment: Qt Mobility is supported on desktops but it's not under active development, see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility/index.html#platform-compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used QT mobility for the desktop.